# PreferenceFragment display

Tags: android

I am new to fragment concept. In my app I have to save user preferences. I have gone through [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).
 Prepared my preferences xml file and PreferenceFragment file. Everything is fine up to now.
My problem is, I have to add the following code in my `onCreate()` method of my `MainActivity`

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
```

It is showing on Main screen. But I want to launch this on a button click method

```
 onSettingsClicked(){
         // launch preferces screen
    }
```

And I want to display it as a separate screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the concept of `fragmentTransaction`.
You need to do the following things-

1. Create a new Fragment.xml to display the button.
2. Invoke the new fragment from the onCreate();
3. Get the Button on the Fragment view.
4. On Button onclick listener replace the the fragment with the SettingFragment().
   Done!

Check out [this FragmentTransaction Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html), it will guide you-

Do the following changes like -

```
// Code not accurate, may be some syntax error  
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
// super and other stuff

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new NewFragment())
            .commit();

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

 @override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, new new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
 }

});


}
```

Comment: looking good. This fragment is adding to current Activity. But i want to display this preference as SubActivity

Comment: Fragment is always added to the Current activity. Fragment is designed for this purpose. You can do what you are looking for by defining you main layout properly. add `<Fragment>` tag in your main layout. to display sub view. have you got my point.

Comment: Yeah got it.. So Intially i will hide this fragment. Then on button click i ll show it to the user. Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fragementTransaction you can use preferenceFragement :
[How do you create Preference Activity and Preference Fragment on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523806/how-do-you-create-preference-activity-and-preference-fragment-on-android) by WannaGetHigh